# Convert Output of Model.Predict to integer

Tags: python, deep-learning, typeconverter

devs I'm using a simple convolutional neural network for binary classification, everything working very well, I'm looking for a method to convert the output of my model prediction to integer (0 or 1).

in the last step I have this instruction :

```
res_f = my_model.predict(test_img)
```

and when i print the value of **res_f** , the result looks like : **[[0. 1.]]**
my problem is about converting **res_f**  to an integer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the model is in One Hot Encoded format.
You can use `argmax` to get the integer equivalent from One Hot Encoded Array.

Code Snippet:

```py
import numpy as np

res_f = my_model.predict(test_img)
result = np.argmax(res_f)
```

Output:

```
1
```